# The correct way to initialize a buffer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, c++14

Which of these is the correct way to initialize a buffer to zero?

```
WCHAR szBuffer[100]={};

WCHAR szBuffer[100]={0};

WCHAR szBuffer[100]={'\0'};

WCHAR szBuffer[100]{};

WCHAR szBuffer[100];
wmemset(szBuffer, '\0', 100);
```

Comment: The first two are equivalent; the third doesn't compile; the fourth is not an initialization (and uses a mysterious and likely incorrect size argument).

Comment: I fixed the third and the fourth one

Comment: Fourth one stil has an incorrect size.

Comment: Now the three first are equivalent, and the fourth definitely has the wrong size argument.

Comment: ok, fixed that one too

Comment: std::array<WCHAR,100> szBuffer{}; Be sure to use range based for loops or use szBuffer.size() in loops later. So you don't have to type 100 all over your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of them are equivalent.

I would avoid (2) and (3) though, because to some they give a false impression that you can put any character in there to fill the array with it, while in reality it only controls the first character of the array, the rest are always zeroed.